# Attempting to load a JavaScript sdk into an Angular2 application. Can't find all dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sdk

I'm attempting to make use of this library: https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-javascript in an Angular2 application.

Unfortunately, I've been going in circles trying to load it into my application.

Firstly, on the TypeScript side if I import it using:

```
import { } from 'mtgsdk';
```

there are no types to load into the {}.

If I attempt to load it using something similar to:

```
import * as mtg from 'mtgsdk'
```

I'm unable to because it says that it's unable to find a module named mtgsdk.

I've installed the module using

```
npm install --save mtgsdk
```

Also, npm installs work fine for other modules.

The application compiles fine if I load it in using require via something similar to this:

```
var mtg = require('mtgsdk');
```

Taking that approach, I'm able to compile and launch but in the browser I get a number of errors about modules that it can't find. I figure they are prerequisites for the sdk that didn't get loaded so I start bringing them in via package.json.

For every one that I bring in, I then have to go to systemjs.config.js and add an entry pointing to the module's entry point and often have to specify a default extension using blocks like this:

*pointer*

```
'mtgsdk': 'npm:mtgsdk/lib/index.js',
'request-promise': 'npm:request-promise/lib/rp.js',
'ramda': 'npm:ramda/dist/ramda.js',
'emitter20': 'npm:emitter20/index.js',
'bluebird': 'npm:bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js',
'request': 'npm:request/index.js'
```

*default extension*

```
 'request-promise':
    {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
```

I'm not sure if that's the right approach though because the more dependencies I add, the more that I end up requiring. At one point I had literally gotten up to 50 extra dependencies added because every time I launched, the browser console would find more that were needed.

Is there any easier way to load all of these in?

Also, some of them (such as tough-cookie and request-promise-core) were very problematic to load and I couldn't get the browser console to stop complaining about them. Finally, some of them seemed very basic such as url, http, https. Those seem like they should already be present.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @oreofeolurin 4.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `systemjs` was utilized in the previous versions of Angular 2, However Angular 2 has evolved to Angular 4, with super new features like [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

I recommend your use Angular CLI, with `@angular/cli`.

**Importing Node modules**

Since `mtgsdk` is a node-module, you can easily import it using

```
import * as mtg from 'mtgsdk'
```

However for your program to compile, you must install a type definition for it. or declare one for it in `/typings.json` or your app might not build.

**Importing Client Scripts**

For client scripts like `firebase.js` you won't need to add client scripts as entries in  `systemjs.config.js` again.

Using `@angular/cli`, you  would easily add them in the `scripts[] array` in your `angular-cli.json` for automatic compilation.

Then access them like this

```
declare const firebase: any;
```

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) is a quickstart tutorial to set up **Angular** with `@angular/cli`.

Comment: I was able to load it in with a cli created app using var mtg = require('mtgsdk'); 

I still get the transpiler hollering at me about not being able to find mtgsdk even though it actually shows up in Intellisense but I can live with that.